# Azure Mobile Services Push Tile Notification and Clear Tile Properties

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-mobile-services

I'm using the Azure Mobile Services Scheduler service to periodically hit another api and send live tile push notifications with updated information. However, sometimes a piece of data is not available from the external api and I need to clear one of the tile properties. The problem is, I can't seem to get the values to clear from the tile when I push out a new notification. I've tried sending null, empty string, and undefined. But nothing I do will clear it. Here is my scheduler code:

```
push.mpns.sendFlipTile(channel.uri, 
{
    title: 'My Title',
    backgroundImage: getTileUrl('front', 'medium', word),
    backBackgroundImage: getTileUrl('back', 'medium', word),
    wideBackgroundImage: getTileUrl('front', 'wide', word),
    wideBackBackgroundImage: getTileUrl('back', 'wide', word),

    backTitle: null,        // Doesn't clear value
    //backTitle: '',        // Doesn't clear value
    //backTitle: undefined, // Doesn't clear value

    count: '0'              // Sending 0 as a string will clear the counter
}, 
{
    success: function(pushResponse) {
        console.log("Sent push:", pushResponse);
    },
    error: function(errorResponse) {
        console.error("Error push:", errorResponse);
    }
});
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for bringing this up. Currently we don't support the ability to clear a value. The addition of the feature is being tracked by [this bug](https://github.com/jeffwilcox/mpns/issues/5). Please help us prioritize fixing this by making an entry on [our UserVoice page](https://mobileservices.uservoice.com)!

Answer (score 1):

According to this documentation:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206971(v=vs.105).aspx

You would need to set Action attribute to Clear for that backTitle.
Don't know how that could be done on Windows Azure Mobile Services MPNS.